# Update column in Excel spreadsheet on change of another column

Tags: excel

I am creating an excel spreadsheet and I just want to know whether is it possible to update one column on selection of an item in another column.

ex: I have a list Country in A column and list of States in B column. can you please let me know when I select a Country in A only those states belongs to A Should be listed in B.

Can anyone advice me how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your problem exactly, what you need is a simple filter.

1. Select your table and put a filter (under Home tab, Sort & Filter).
2. Check the country you want to see the states of (click the little grey box with black arrow for the A column).

After that, only those states that belong to the country you selected should be visible.

Now, if the state is wrong, it means your original data is wrong.